# Load textdomain from global languages directory

Tags: plugin-development, translation, textdomain

I am creating translations for my plugin.
To fetch **.mo** files from my-plugin/languages directory , I use the function

```
//Load translation
function load_plugin_textdomain() {
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'my-plugin', FALSE, basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/' );
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'load_plugin_textdomain' );
```

How can i set the location to **wp-content/languages** 
Setting the location to `ABSPATH.'/wp-content/languages'` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody else is looking for the anwser , Here it is

```
function load_txtdomain() {
    $locale = apply_filters( 'plugin_locale', get_locale(), 'my-plugin' );
    load_textdomain( 'my-plugin', WP_LANG_DIR . '/my-plugin-' . $locale . '.mo' );
}
add_action('plugins_loaded','load_txtdomain');
```